# IIS web application subdomain

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a little problem. I know that its possible to configure sub domains on my local Machine using host file settings and creating new WEBSITE within iis 7.
Let's say I have an IIS web site. And within it I have another web application defined as application folder not just as a virtual folder (which runs it under same process).

Basically I can access my apps like

```
Example
http://mydomain.com/app1
http://mydomain.com/app2
```

i want it to be

```
http://app1.mydomain.com
http://app2.mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100463/asp-net-multi-tenant-application) for the answer to this question. Sorry for the repetition

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is an answer at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/26166/how-to-create-a-subdomain-in-iis7).

Basically, create two web sites and set the host header on each to app*.mydomain.com.

But you could also use the [IIS7 URL Rewriting Module](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite), and there is an example of use, again at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/143442/using-iis-url-rewrite-how-to-rewrite-foo-bar-com-bar-com-myapp)

Answer (score 0):

Create new websites with that hostheader and set the directory to that on the local file system of 
http://mydomain.com/app1

i.e.

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app1

Comment: thanks dude but i really want to have only one Website containing may web application. I have tried what your proposing and its works but thats not my option for now